# Dificuldade com Assincronismo - JavaScript/ReactJs/Google Maps/Distance Matrix API

Tags: javascript, react, google-maps

Boa tarde pessoal,

Sou novo na área e estou com dificuldade em desenvolver um código que execute a Função2 somente após o retorno da Função1.

Como posso ajustar o código para que a Função2 execute somente após o retorno da Função1?

```
functionExample = () => {
    var distance = require('google-distance-matrix')
    var origins = [location1]
    var destinations = [location2]

// Função1:

    distance.matrix(origins, destinations, (err, distances) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err, 'status', distances1.status)
        console.log("Erro")}

      if (distances.status === "OK") {
        ArrayExample.push((distances.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value / 1000))}
    })

// Função2:

functionExample2()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, bem vindo ao mundo de Javascript o que você pretende alcançar são funções assíncronas, recomendo a leitura da documentação de Promisses para entender melhor o que está acontecendo mas uma solução para o seu problema é simples, o retorno de "distance.matrix" é uma promisse, a partir disso pode abstrair para uma variavel utilizando async / await, ficaria algo como :

```
const response = await distance.matrix(origins, destinations)
```

Lembre-se de tornar sua função assíncrona para evitar valores indefinidos para isso faça :

```
async functionExample() { ... <bloco da sua função>
```

Seguindo essa estratégia ao chamar functionExample() ela vai retornar uma promisse e você pode trata-las com then & catch

A chamada para sua função assíncrona

```
functionExample().then((resultado) => {
// aqui vai poder utilizar seu resultado
}).catch((erro) => {
// aqui vai cair quando tiver um erro em sua função   
})
```

Espero que tenha entendido e possa utilizar funções assíncronas sem mais problemas agora.